# How to load a file in Azure Function using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions

I have a small function that takes an array of US telephone area codes and returns an array of area codes paired to the state they are in.

The "master list" of area codes to states is a long variable in my function. I'd like to put that in a CSV file instead.

I'm a beginner to using Azure Functions but, even when the file is in the root folder, `Get-Content .\filename.csv` does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path to your Azure Function directory is

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot\<YourFunctionName>
```

To load the CSV file, use the following in your PowerShell script,

```
Get-Content D:\home\site\wwwroot\<YourFunctionName>\filename.csv
```

Here's a sample output for loading the areacode-to-state mapping file,

```
2017-03-11T09:21:57.185 Function started (Id=9c93e8cf-4cf0-487e-b86e-02e57b41b8de)
2017-03-11T09:21:58.357 Area code,State,State code
2017-03-11T09:21:58.357 201,New Jersey,NJ
2017-03-11T09:21:58.357 202,"Washington,DC",DC
2017-03-11T09:21:58.357 203,Connecticut,CT
2017-03-11T09:21:58.357 205,Alabama,AL
....<more logging>....
```

**Additional tooling and resources:** 

**i. Kudu console -** You may use the Kudu console to navigate through the directory structure of your Function App.  I sometimes use the Kudu console to test the `run.ps1` script outside the Azure Functions runtime.

To use the Kudu console, perform the following steps:

1. Visit the Azure Functions Portal for your Function App.
2. Click on **Function app settings -> Go to Kudu -> Debug Console -> PowerShell**.
3. Navigate to your Function directory and run your script as shown in the snapshot below. 

   [image]

**ii. Bring your own modules -** You may also load your own custom modules and use them in your `run.ps1` script. Details on how to achieve this are provide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724769/how-to-install-a-powershell-module-in-an-azure-function/39985646#39985646).

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

It's never really a good idea to reference absolute paths as things may change. To use a variable that will always point you to the correct path you can use:

`$EXECUTION_CONTEXT_FUNCTIONDIRECTORY` which will return the current folder your Azure Functions runs from.

To use this in your question at hand:

```
Get-Content -Path "$EXECUTION_CONTEXT_FUNCTIONDIRECTORY\filename.csv"
```

Documentation on this:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Retrieving-information-about-the-currently-running-function#powershell-php-python-bash-batch-and-other-scripting-languages

Comment: this is what I was looking for, thanks so much. Worked for me in the azure funciton using powershell

Answer (score 0):

I ran this search in app service console:

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot>set | findstr /c:wwwroot
AZURE_JETTY93_CMDLINE=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djetty.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -Djetty.base="D:\Program Files (x86)\jetty-distribution-9.3.25.v20180904" -Djetty.webapps="d:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps"  -jar "D:\Program Files (x86)\jetty-distribution-9.3.25.v20180904\start.jar" etc\jetty-logging.xml

AZURE_JETTY9_CMDLINE=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djetty.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -Djetty.base="D:\Program Files (x86)\jetty-distribution-9.1.0.v20131115" -Djetty.webapps="d:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps"  -jar "D:\Program Files (x86)\jetty-distribution-9.1.0.v20131115\start.jar" etc\jetty-logging.xml

DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=D:\home\site\wwwroot

WEBROOT_PATH=D:\home\site\wwwroot
```

It seems like you can use DEPLOYMENT_TARGET or WEBROOT_PATH environment variables as the base path to your resource file too.