# PowerShell script and libeay32.dll with Azure Function App

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to use a PowerShell script that works on my machine in an Azure Function App.

In short, the script uses a Service Principal profile json to login to Azure and then does some magic to renew my Let's Encrypt SSL certificate.

The script itself is in a file called Register-LetsEncryptCertificateSP.ps1 and I can run it successfully in local PowerShell ISE by calling it like this:
`PS C:\tmp\test> .\Register-LetsEncryptCertificateSP.ps1 -Domain dev.mysite.com -RegistrationEmail my@email.com -ResourceGroup my-resourcegroup-name -WebApp my-webapp-name -ServicePrincipalProfilePath "c:\tmp\letsencryptSP.json"`.

I added Service Principal support to Lee Holmes's script which prompts for Azure account credentials by default: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Register-LetsEncryptCertificate/1.0/DisplayScript

I'm trying to put this script inside a TimerTriggerPowerShell Function App. The script requires following modules: `#requires -Modules AcmeSharp, Azure, AzureRM.Websites`

`Azure` and `AzureRM.Websites` are available by default and I have uploaded ACMESharp to `modules/` -directory` but when I run the script in Azure I get the following log:

```
2017-04-03T09:46:23.499 Function started (Id=015f9081-8bc2-4801-b392-76e53da027f7)
2017-04-03T09:46:23.983 Loaded modules:
/TimerTriggerPowerShell1/modules/ACMESharp/0.8.1/ACMESharp.psd1
/TimerTriggerPowerShell1/modules/ACMESharp/0.8.1/ACMESharp-AWS/ACMESharp-AWS.psd1
/TimerTriggerPowerShell1/modules/ACMESharp/0.8.1/ACMESharp-IIS/ACMESharp-IIS.psd1
/TimerTriggerPowerShell1/modules/ACMESharp/0.8.1/ACMESharp.dll
/TimerTriggerPowerShell1/modules/ACMESharp/0.8.1/ACMESharp.PKI.Providers.OpenSslLib32.dll
/TimerTriggerPowerShell1/modules/ACMESharp/0.8.1/ACMESharp.PKI.Providers.OpenSslLib64.dll
/TimerTriggerPowerShell1/modules/ACMESharp/0.8.1/ACMESharp.POSH-test.dll
/TimerTriggerPowerShell1/modules/ACMESharp/0.8.1/ACMESharp.POSH.dll
/TimerTriggerPowerShell1/modules/ACMESharp/0.8.1/ACMESharp.Providers.AWS.dll
/TimerTriggerPowerShell1/modules/ACMESharp/0.8.1/ACMESharp.Providers.IIS.dll
/TimerTriggerPowerShell1/modules/ACMESharp/0.8.1/ACMESharp.Vault.dll
/TimerTriggerPowerShell1/modules/ACMESharp/0.8.1/AWSSDK.Core.dll
/TimerTriggerPowerShell1/modules/ACMESharp/0.8.1/AWSSDK.Route53.dll
/TimerTriggerPowerShell1/modules/ACMESharp/0.8.1/AWSSDK.S3.dll
/TimerTriggerPowerShell1/modules/ACMESharp/0.8.1/ManagedOpenSsl.dll
/TimerTriggerPowerShell1/modules/ACMESharp/0.8.1/Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll
/TimerTriggerPowerShell1/modules/ACMESharp/0.8.1/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
/TimerTriggerPowerShell1/modules/ACMESharp/0.8.1/x86/libeay32.dll
/TimerTriggerPowerShell1/modules/ACMESharp/0.8.1/x86/ssleay32.dll
/TimerTriggerPowerShell1/modules/ACMESharp/0.8.1/ACMESharp-AWS/ACMESharp-AWS.psm1
/TimerTriggerPowerShell1/modules/ACMESharp/0.8.1/ACMESharp-IIS/ACMESharp-IIS.psm1
2017-04-03T09:46:24.186 Import-Module : The specified module 'AWSPowerShell' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
at <ScriptBlock>, /TimerTriggerPowerShell1/modules/ACMESharp/0.8.1/ACMESharp-AWS/ACMESharp-AWS.psm1: line 17
+ Import-Module
+ _____________
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (AWSPowerShell:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
2017-04-03T09:46:24.280 Function completed (Failure, Id=015f9081-8bc2-4801-b392-76e53da027f7)
2017-04-03T09:46:24.343 Exception while executing function: Functions.TimerTriggerPowerShell1. System.Management.Automation: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTriggerPowerShell1\modules\ACMESharp\0.8.1\x86\libeay32.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
```

The app service is running on 32bit. Any ideas how to solve this error?

Comment: Try comparing the version of powershell on functions / locally (`$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`).

Also, try logging into your functions scm site (kudu) and running your powershell script from there.

Comment: The error states that it could not load the AWSPowerShell which is used by ACMESharp.  Try adding AWSPowerShell to the modules folder as demonstrated in this SO thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724769/how-to-install-a-powershell-module-in-an-azure-function/39985646#39985646