# Azure Function - PowerShell, installing az cmdlet :: The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions, azure-cli

I am attempting to install the `az` cmdlet onto Kudu for my Azure Function. I am currently following this guide:

[How to install a PowerShell module in an Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724769/how-to-install-a-powershell-module-in-an-azure-function)

... however - I am still getting the following error within my Azure Function:

`az : The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
at run.ps1: line 1`

**Steps I have done till now:**

- Created a `module` folder under `D:\home\site\wwwroot\Communication_with_Azure_Container_Registry\>`
- Within the `module` folder I have added the contents of `azure-cli/2.0.35/...`,  (which looks like this): [image]

  ... Azure Function code is very simple to proof out the ability to install the cmdlet:

  ```
  if (-not (Get-Module -Name "az"))
  {
    Write-Output "azure-cli not installed";
  }
  else
  {
    Write-Output "azure-cli installed";
  }

  $test = 'az --help'
  Invoke-Expression $test
  Write-output `n$test
  ```

*Question*:

- Is there something within my configuration that is not allowing for the `az` cmdlet to install?
- Is there an alternative way to gain access to the `azure-cli` without implementing the `node` module?

Comment: The question you're linking to is about the Azure PowerShell cmdlets, not the az-cli, which is a cross-platform cli that runs on python. I'm unaware of any way to install the az-cli on azure app service through kudu. You probably can get it to work if you get python 3.6 on the machine, and then get the cli there manually, but I never tried it and I have no idea if it'll actually run.

Comment: I upgraded and was able to run `python.exe -m pip install azure-cli` but I am not sure where that was saved ...

Comment: What is your goal, to run the Azure CLI 2 (python) from an Azure Function OR to run the Azure Powershell Commandlets from an Azure Function?  If your goal is the former I think your are going to run into issues authenticating via the CLI to actually run any commands.

Comment: @KWilson my goal is to authenticate via the `azure-cli` from my Azure Function in order to communicate with my Azure Container Registry - to invoke a Docker container as a Azure Instance Container.

Answer (score 4):

I solved the following part of your problem

> az : The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. at run.ps1: line 1

If you execute

```
Test-Path -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin'
```

You will probably get False. This means that you need to install the Azure CLI eg from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?view=azure-cli-latest

Answer (score 1):

I haven't testing this myself, but according to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/02/24/using-powershell-modules-in-azure-functions/ you should be able to do an Import-Module. In their example...

```
Write-Output “Loading Wunderlist Module”
import-module ‘D:\Home\site\wwwroot\HttpTriggerPowerShellDemo\Modules\Wunderlist\1.0.10\Wunderlist.psm1’
$Result = Get-Help Get-WunderlistUser | Out-String
Write-Output $Result
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Azure CLI
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest

This should give you the az command