# How to install a PowerShell module on an Azure web app without administrator permissions?

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service

I am working on an internal tool that is meant to automatize app deployment on Azure. It is actually an MVC application where a user can upload zip-packages containing other apps and afterwards those get deployed on Azure (each of them to its own app service). Until now I was using "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent" in C# which made things easy. Unfortunately it didn't allow me to make the kind of configurations I needed to make especially on Application gateway. Fortunately PowerShell does. I have already wrote the script that does everything I need. I can publish that script in my azure web app. The problem is that `AzureRM` module (which is a required module) is missing there. Also, I am not able to install it since I get an "You are not an administrator..." error (likely because I'm not an administrator on the actual Azure web app). Any ideas on how to install a PS module in an Azure web app?

Update:
I know I can use Azure API in order to achieve my goal, but I would like to be able to run a normal PowerShell script (at least it's more readable).

Update 2 :)
It seems like there is no way to install a PS module beside an web app since resources are shared and so on. I have decided to abandon using powershell with azureRM and execute api calls from my c# app.

Comment: can you just copy it over? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724769/how-to-install-a-powershell-module-in-an-azure-function

Comment: No, unfortunately that doesn't work for me. I've tried to use AzureRM that is already present on an WebApp but the version doesn't fit my requirements.

Comment: I posted some reference materials.  If you need more help, please give us code for your PowerShell that is managing the installed modules

Comment: Just as a suggestion, if you can't find the powershell module you need, you can always use the API. Have you tried running Powershell as administrator to install the module?

Comment: can you post the script you wrote?

Comment: Not trying to pick on you, but it isn't totally clear to me exactly what you are asking for...

Comment: When you say app deployment, is this deployment of code e.g. another mvc web app, or deployment of infrastructure e.g. creating an azure website / sql server etc?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to install the module version you need to the current user environment (use Az module instead of AzureRM):

```
Install-Module -Name Az.Websites  -Scope CurrentUser
```

Tale a note that AzureRM is not recommended anymore:

> Because Az PowerShell modules now have all the capabilities of AzureRM
> PowerShell modules and more, we'll retire AzureRM PowerShell modules
> on 29 February 2024.
> We do not support having both the AzureRM and Az modules installed for
> PowerShell 5.1 on Windows at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If the version on the environment is not compatible with your requirements try to uninstall it first.

How to uninstall the AzureRM module to re-install a different version - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/uninstall-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-6.13.0

Install Azure RM Module with Power Shell - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-6.13.0

Comment: I am deploying my app on azure as a web app. I need actually a newer version of azurerm on that. There is already one. But I need more than that.

Comment: @coceban.vlad so how can I help? Not sure what your point is?