# Error of Assembly with same name is already loaded doing Import-Module in Azure Function

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

In an Azure Function I am trying to load a PowerShell module but getting the error Assembly with same
name is already loaded.

**Code Sample**

```
Import-Module "D:\home\site\wwwroot\HelloWorld\modules\MsrcSecurityUpdates\1.7.2\MsrcSecurityUpdates.psd1"
```

**Error Message**

```
Import-Module : Assembly with same name is already loaded
At C:\home\site\wwwroot\HelloWorld\run.ps1:25 char:5
+     Import-Module "D:\home\site\wwwroot\HelloWorld\modules\MsrcSecuri ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Import-Module], FileLoadException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatXmlUpdateException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

**Some additional background..**

This code was working yesterday. I have made a lot of edits so cannot clearly state the same code which was working yesterday is now failing.

I am editing the code directly via the browser.

I have restarted the web app, to potentially flush out any assemblies loaded during my code. Did not make a difference.

I checked if the module is available with the following, which returns the MsrcSecurityUpdates is NOT installed.

```
if (-not (Get-Module -Name "MsrcSecurityUpdates"))
{
    Write-Output "MsrcSecurityUpdates NOT installed";
}
else
{
    Write-Output "MsrcSecurityUpdates YES installed";
}
```

I downloaded the module with

```
Save-Module -Name MsrcSecurityUpdates -Path "C:\TEMP" -Force
```

and subsequently uploaded to the Azure Function File Share using the Kudo console. As per the steps outlined in this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724769/how-to-install-a-powershell-module-in-an-azure-function)

Comment: The [other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39985646/2266713) seems to indicate that the modules are loaded automatically (and you don't need to `Import-Module`. Does your log output show your module being loaded?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work that way. Later in the script, functions from the module are failing as it's not loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This module seems to conflict with other modules in your app, or with assemblies loaded explicitly from your code. It is also possible that the module content is corrupted.

First of all, I would recommend relying on the [Managed Dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell#dependency-management) feature instead of uploading the module via Kudu. Just include a reference to your module into the `requirements.psd1` file at the root of your app:

```
@{
    ...
    'MsrcSecurityUpdates' = '1.*'
}
```

If you edit this file in the Portal, you may need to restart your app. The next time you invoke any function, the latest version of this module will be automatically installed from the PowerShell Gallery and will be available on PSModulePath, so you can import it without specifying any path:

```
Import-Module MsrcSecurityUpdates
```

Try this on a brand new app without any other modules: MsrcSecurityUpdates will be loaded. However, if you are still getting the same error, this means MsrcSecurityUpdates is in conflict with other modules your app is using. You can narrow it down by removing other modules from your app (including cleaning up the modules uploaded via Kudu) and reducing your code.

**[UPDATE]** Potential workarounds:

- Try to import (`Import-Module`) the modules in a certain fixed order, to make sure the more recent assembly versions are loaded first. This may or may not help, depending on the design of the modules.
- Try executing commands from one of the modules in a separate process (using PowerShell jobs or sessions, or even invoking pwsh.exe).

Comment: That has worked. I had to create two separate functions for the MsrcSecurityUpdates functions & the Azure Storage functions. All in one script was failing. I also suspect the modules I uploaded via Kudu were corrupted because I could not get original function working.

Comment: Further addition. The two functions ONLY succeeded when the app was restarted between them. The assemblies were in conflict, so could not both be loaded at the same time. Have to re-architect the process.

Comment: @BenOnline I updated the answer with potential workarounds.